# Inkscape 0.91: How does one convert symbols to a path?

Tags: inkscape

I'm using Inkscape 0.91 and opened the Object > Symbols menu to use the various icons. When I try to convert a symbol to a path, nothing happens. How can I edit paths on symbols?

Comment: This is the kind of question which might be a good fit for the proposed Graphic Design Software Support stack. Please see the proposal and follow it if you think it might be useful. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86994/graphic-design-software-support/

Comment: Why is it necessary to separate questions about theory and implementation? Those two aspects benefit from each other and the tagging system on stack exchange allows clean separation anyway.

Comment: This is an ongoing discussion on the site. The community has collectively decided that we don't want to be Adobe/Inkscape etc. support, but there are many many people coming here with basic-to-moderate how-to questions (like yours). These questions are often quickly closed or migrated to SuperUser. As an alternative, I recently proposed creating a new stack just for these questions, and I'm promoting the proposal where appropriate.

Comment: If this is what the community is clamoring for, then I'm in support of having a place to ask software specific questions. However I disagree with the community's premise that there needs to be separation because there are already mechanisms to ignore well labeled questions related to software (like mine). I believe implementation and theory should be part of the same knowledge base. Thanks for helping to clarify this for me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The symbol is like a clone: 
select the symbol and Edit > Clone > Unlink Clone (Shift+Alt+D), and you have a group, ungroup (Object > Ungroup, or Shift+Ctrl+G) and edit.