# Apply SVG clipPath to geometry

Tags: svg, software-recommendation

I have some SVG images which contain `clipPath` elements. I am working in an environment that doesn't render `clipPath` elements. **What tool or software can I use to apply the** `clipPath` **to the SVG geometry so that the output file is visually equivalent but contains no instances of** `clipPath`**?**

Comment: Interesting question! Could you provide a simple svg for a MWE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this using Inkscape.

## The manual way

If you're only doing a few drawings, doing it by hand like this might be acceptable.

It is possible to manually convert paths that use a `clip-path` to a normal path in Inkscape by using one of Inkscape's path Boolean operations (division, union, etc).

1. Select the object with the `clip-path` attribute.
   If you don't know what objects have a clip path, on the **Edit** menu, click **XML Editor**. When you select an object, if it has a clip path, you will see a value for `clip-path`. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to search that path id.
2. On the **Object** menu, hover over **Clip**, and then click **Release**
3. With the objects still selected on the **Path** menu, click **Intersection**.

This has several caveats:

- It is manual and tedious work
- It doesn't work if the clip path involves more than two paths. ([The Multi-Bool extension may help](https://inkscape.org/nl/~Moini/%E2%98%85multi-bool-extension-cut-difference-division), otherwise, you'd have to duplicate the clipPath so it can be used more than once)
- Intersection may not have the expected effect for some clipping paths; you may need to duplicate the object and perform multiple path operations.

## The PDF to SVG way

Don't have the patience to edit files by hand? You can use Inkscape like a proverbial axe. Clip those clip paths!

Inkscape can save in a few vector formats, but some formats will lose data. In this case, you can actually use this to your advantage.

1. In Inkscape, save the SVG file that has clip paths as a PDF (Save as, then in the file type select PDF).
2. Close Inkscape.
3. Open the PDF in Inkscape.
4. Save as SVG.

The drawing *will* be structurally changed (you might have different groups or what was previously a path with a stroke and fill might now be two paths). This changes will make the drawing more difficult to edit manually, but for the most part the drawing should still be OK (depending on what it was).

## The automated way?

Inkscape has command line operations, but I don't know enough to say if they might help.

If you are looking to automate this, my approach would be to look for a program or library to convert to PDF, then convert the PDF back to SVG.

## The cop-out way

Export to PNG using Inkscape or one of a few different programs that can render an SVG to a raster image. Sure, you gave up and took the lazy way out, but hey, it was quick!

Comment: Thank you immensely; manually editing the files in Inkscape worked perfectly for my use case. If the clipping path is a clone, it must be converted to a path following [this answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53227/inkscape-0-91-how-does-one-convert-symbols-to-a-path) for the Intersection operator to work. Also, the SVG -> PDF -> SVG approach occasionally preserved the `clip-path`s.