# SVG looks different in Inkscape than elsewhere

Tags: inkscape

I'm experiencing an issue where my SVG graphics are missing elements when displayed outside of Inkscape. The Inkscape image is (including the document border):

[image]

However, I've tried displaying this in Firefox, Chromium and Anki and they all show an identical output:

[image]

I've done some searching for this, but most of the reported issues relate to problems with fonts, which isn't my issue (I converted them to paths). I've also tried different svg output file formats (plain and optimized with various settings, including max decimal places) but nothing seems to change the result.

The missing components (I'm using a custom symbol library) have displayed fine in other schematics and I haven't been able to figure out any pattern as to when it works. I'm using the "default px" template and Inkscape version 0.92.2 on ArchLinux with KDE Plasma.

Here's a link to the [file on DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lfx4zjc1g8lntvw/emitter-follower.svg?dl=0).

Comment: Hi MattHusz is it possible to share a sample file? it maybe easier to give some answers

Comment: @Junme I've amended the original post so that it now contains a link to file mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

those symbles have no stroke colour

it seems the center symbol has colour

this will change them now:

select the symbol, then right click,

select same > object type,

then  edit >clone > unlink clone

then fill and stroke  > stroke paint

it should default to black, pick if not

good luck

from this post

[Inkscape 0.91: How does one convert symbols to a path?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53227/inkscape-0-91-how-does-one-convert-symbols-to-a-path)

Answer (score 3):

While the above fix by @Junme works, it also gets rid of the purpose of employing symbols in the first place, and it does give a wrong reason. The styles of both kinds of symbols - those that are displayed, and those that are not, are identical. The objects in question all have a stroke color (which is black, or #000000).

The issue is with the transforms on the objects. The original symbols have been created outside the page border, and the browser doesn't display things outside the page border, while Inkscape does, of course. Just changing the page size will fix the problem.

Or recreating the symbols while having the originals placed in the area where the visible drawing will be.

This is what it looks like when the page size is changed just a little bit (and ~50% of the symbol original is inside the page (viewbox) borders):

[image]

Comment: Oh interesting. If I understand you correctly though, the solutions seem a bit inconvenient. Either I need to make the circuit SVG page size big enough to encompass the position at which the original symbols were created, or recreate my symbols such that they fit in the SVG files where they will be used. In regard to the first solution, I'd like to make the page just large enough to encompass the circuit and for the second solution I'd like to create symbols once without knowing beforehand where they will be used. Have I understood correctly? Is there an easier solution to this?

Comment: You could use ready-made symbols, or you could create a symbol file that is formatted correctly and can be used in all kinds of projects.

CircuitTikz is part of the open-symbols set: https://github.com/Xaviju/inkscape-open-symbols , screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/fmTYGwo.png  

To make your own universal electrical symbols, create a file that is comparable to the symbol files in that repository.